# Does Parallels 10 fix the Fn keys issue?

Tags: parallels-desktop

In order to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> Keys on Windows VMs with Parallels 9 you have to set them as standard function keys on Mac OS, which requires you the press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to access the special functions (brightness, playback, volume etc.).

Does Parallels 10 fix this, allowing you to use the special keys on Mac and the F keys on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

parallels can't 'fix' this issue, because the Fn+FKey combination is done in the keyboard itself, before being sent to the OS.

The Fn key itself does send a key code, but the combo doesn't.